# Multiple statements in a loop with if else

Tags: objective-c

EDIT: Updated code to better reflect my problem

this code returns 9 strings to badDestination1

```
NSMutableArray* goodDestination1 = [NSMutableArray array];
NSMutableArray* badDestination1 = [NSMutableArray array];
NSMutableArray* badDestination2 = [NSMutableArray array];

for (NSString* item in sourceArray)
{
    if ([item rangeOfString:@"<b>"].location != NSNotFound)

        [goodDestination1 addObject:item];

    else {
        [badDestination1 addObject:item];
        //[badDestination2 addObject:@"Title"];
    }
}
```

This code returns 1 value to badDestination2

```
for (NSString* item in sourceArray)
    {
        if ([item rangeOfString:@"<b>"].location != NSNotFound)

            [goodDestination1 addObject:item];

        else {
            //[badDestination1 addObject:item];
            [badDestination2 addObject:@"String"];
        }
    }
```

anyone know whats going on?
Seems like the "String" might be getting rewritten in the same location on the array maybe?

Comment: How many items are there in `stringSource`? If the count is 1 then it will surely only be called once.

Comment: I am positive there are at least 9 items being put into arrayDestinationBad1

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Looks like you're missing the braces `{}` after the `else`.

```
else {
  [arrayDestinationBad1 addObject:item]; 
  [arrayDestinationBad2 addObject:@"String"]; 
}
```

Comment: He says it only gets called once (obviously implying he wants it called more often).  Without the braces it /should/ get called every time through the loop.

Comment: @Matthew: That's true, but what else could be the problem with that code?

Comment: I don't know, but adding the braces can only make it run less (<=) often. :)

Comment: Perhaps it was mis-copied and that statement is actually *outside* the loop. That's the only thing I can think of.

Comment: for (NSString* item in doesntContainAnother2)
 {
  if ([item rangeOfString:@"<b>"].location != NSNotFound) {
   
   [containsAnother3 addObject:item];
   
  } else {
   [doesntContainAnother3 addObject:item];
   [doesntContainAnother3Titles addObject:@"Title"];
  }
 }

That still only calls it once. Is it possible my string is overwriting itself in the array?

Comment: it can vary, but the source is a really big string. I am using this as a method to weed out HTML tags to make parsing simple.

Comment: @S-T-R-E-G-A *(and by the way, that name is a pain to type ;) )* : Can you use a debugger and step through the code? That is likely to be much more revealing than anything we tell you. If not, how are you checking the destination array afterwards? Are you certain it only has one element?

Comment: @mmyers I think your right. I may have jumped to conclusions. with nslog showing array.count on both arrays I return values from 9 (what I want) and 1092 (no idea where that is comming from...). I will study what I am doing a little more!

Comment: figured it out... I was writing the "String" to a key value in a dictionary of a plist so it just wrote the same key over and over updating the value. Result was 1 key with the last value. :(
How embarrassing... but I figured it out. Thanks for the assistance guys!

Comment: So it was a dictionary and not an array? Tsk, tsk. ;)